# MyISAM or columnstore for bigdata?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam, columnstore

I have big CSV logs (about 1TB). What engine I should use for storing them? I had read that Column store is developed for such cases but what is it real advantages on MyISAM?

Comment: dont use MyIsam tables for this. if someone write to the table the hole table is locked. MyIsam supported only table lock

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? I assume you want to store it in a database to be able to index and query it, yes?

Comment: As logs, I assume the data is "append-only"?  That is, you won't ever do `UPDATE` or `DELETE`?  What kinds of reads will you do?  One cannot make a judgement call without understanding the usage of the data.  Please provide tentative `SELECTs`.